# RequestOptions migration Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I was using a custom request options in Angular 4 where I was doing the following:

default-request-options.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });

  merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
    var newOptions = super.merge(options);
    const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      newOptions.headers.set('token', token);
    }
    return newOptions;
  }
}
```

App.Module.ts

```
providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }
  ]
```

But after the migration notice that the RequestOption is not available in the new folder http/common/http

I'm would like to know if I still can use similar thing in Angular 5 or there is no point using it with the new HTTPClient? The main advantage for me was to set in one place only, not having to append it to all my requests.

I got the code initially in the angular docs: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/server-communication/ts/src/app/default-request-options.service.ts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-new-headers) to add default headers to your requests. Example from the angular docs:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Get the auth header from the service.
    const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like interceptors is a way to go, exacly what I was looking for and a big more. Tks

Comment: Hi, I'm re-factoring very similar service, but from where you getting the "AuthService"?

Comment: Hi, how can I change "headers" value for uploading file..? Because in uploading file it's also taking a content-Type', 'application/json'` and i want to add `multipart/form-data`. Can you help me..?