# Angular 6 - Deprecated methods

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to change the request options but it's deprecated. I can't find the option for this.

Any help?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl:string = 'http://localhost:8080/api';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  private options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers});

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: from which version did you switch to angular 6?

Comment: angular 0.......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequestOptions migration Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585720/requestoptions-migration-angular-5)

Comment: I don't think his intention was to intercept every call to set default headers, but rather to switch from the deprecated `RequestOptions` to a  current solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is just an import problem, because they moved these options to another place. The documentation states:

> use @angular/common/http instead

So I guess you just have to import the options from `@angular/common/http` instead of `@angular/http`

### EDIT

I should have looked a bit closer. Headers can now be send a bit differently than before, you don't have to use `RequestOptions` anymore, just pack it up as a simple object. In your case it could look like  this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};
```

Then you can use these options with your http methods. Here's an example from angular's [fundamentals](https://angular.io/guide/http#headers):

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

Comment: const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json', 'Api-Key' : '5454343434'
  })
};  Here i am passing API-key as shown above but i am getting the Error " OPTIONS " 400 Error

Answer (score 1):

**Deprecated APIs and Features**

```
Headers -> HttpHeaders
RequestOptions -> HttpRequest
HttpModule -> HttpClientModule
```

Old

```
import {HttpModule, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
```

New

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Refer the following URL for more details: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations