# How to convert Http call?

Tags: angular, http, youtube-api

I need to convert this deprecated get http query in Angular 6. I have the error:

> json isn't a function

.This is my code:

```
search(query: string): Observable < YoutubeSearchResult > {
    const params: string =[
        `q=${query}`,
        `key=${this.apikey}`,
        `part=snippet`,
        `type=video`,
        `maxResult=10`
    ].join('&');

    const queryUrl = `${this.apiurl}?${params}`;
    //  const queryUrl = "";


    /**ritorna richiesta http get oppure con Httpclient (POST,DELETE,GET), usp map per il Response
     * e estraggo l'oggetto usando.json e itero il risultato e lo converto in SearchResult
     */

    return this.http.get(queryUrl).map((response: Response) => {

        return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
            return new YoutubeSearchResult({

                id: item.id.videoId,
                title: item.snippet.title,
                description: item.snippet.description,
                thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
            });

        })


    });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 - Deprecated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346275/angular-6-deprecated-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  search(query: string): Observable<YoutubeSearchResult[]> {
    const params: string = [
      `q=${query}`,
      `key=${this.apikey}`,
      `part=snippet`,
      `type=video`,
      `maxResult=10`
    ].join('&');

    const queryUrl = `${this.apiurl}?${params}`;

    return this.http.get(queryUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(
          (youTubeData: any) => {
            const items = [];
            console.log(youTubeData);
            youTubeData.items.forEach(x => {
              items.push(
                new YoutubeSearchResult(
                  x.id.videoId,
                  x.snippet.title,
                  x.snippet.description,
                  x.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
                )
              );
            });
            return items;
          }
        )
    );
```

Call it like this:

```
  findStuff() {
    this.search('lazy').subscribe((searchResults: YoutubeSearchResult[]) => {
      console.log('search results: ', searchResults);
    });
  }
```